# Jest functions export

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I'm using jest+puppeteer and I have a code that I'd like to reuse across my project.

I use the following instruction:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started

```js
//adminLogin2.js
const admLog = function admLog () {
     return
     page.goto(data.config.env.host);
     page.waitForSelector(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login);
     page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login);
     page.type(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login, data.credentials.business_email.login);
     page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.form_button_first);

    // second step
     page.waitForSelector(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login_password);
     page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login_password);
     page.type(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login_password, data.credentials.business_email.password);
     page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.form_button_second);
     page.waitForSelector(data.selectors.admin.auth.business_login_button);
     page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.business_login_button);
     page.waitForSelector(data.selectors.admin.auth.business_body);

}


module.exports = admLog;
```

```js
//test

const data =   require('../config');
const admLog = require('../struct/Login/adminLogin2');


describe('GetPackage :: Auth', () => {

    it('Admin Email', async () => {
        await admLog();

    });
});
```

Test could be run without exceptions, but nothing happens, in headless:false mode Chrome is just run and closed.

What should be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the `async/await` in the `admLog` function.
2. Remove the `return` statement to prevent the [Automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)

So the final `adminLogin2.js` file should be like this:

```js
//adminLogin2.js
const admLog = async function() {
    await page.goto(data.config.env.host);
    await page.waitForSelector(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login);
    await page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login);
    await page.type(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login, data.credentials.business_email.login);
    await page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.form_button_first);

    // second step
    await page.waitForSelector(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login_password);
    await page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login_password);
    await page.type(data.selectors.admin.auth.input_login_password, data.credentials.business_email.password);
    await page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.form_button_second);
    await page.waitForSelector(data.selectors.admin.auth.business_login_button);
    await page.click(data.selectors.admin.auth.business_login_button);
    await page.waitForSelector(data.selectors.admin.auth.business_body);
}

module.exports = admLog;
```